# Android Retain previous scroll position of listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a problem with my listview. My listview has a custom adapter. It fetches records from server. I use `AsyncTask` to fetch the records and display in the listview.

But when I click the listview item to display the detail and go back to the list activity, it scrolls to the top and refresh the listview.

This is my code:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if (isSwiped) {
                // reset
                isSwiped = false;
            }

            if (result != null && tag == 1) {
                adapter = new SharedBibleVersesAdapter(SharedBibleVersesActivity.this,
                        SharedBibleVersesActivity.this);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    displayRecords();
 }

public void displayRecords() {

    if(ConnectionDetector.hasNetworkConnection(this)) {
        DisplayAsyncTask displayTask = new DisplayAsyncTask();
        displayTask.execute();
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tvHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvHeader.setText(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_connection));

    }

}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tvTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.shared_bible_verses));
    tvHeader = (MyTextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    progressBar = (ProgressWheel) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    displayRecords();

}
```

Any ideas why it's scrolling to the top? I'd gladly appreciate any kind of help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's scrolling to the top because you're setting the adapter again...

Use:

```
if (adapter == null) {
    adapter = new SharedBibleVersesAdapter(SharedBibleVersesActivity.this, SharedBibleVersesActivity.this, itemList, userAPIkey, userId);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
} else {
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it's still scrolling to top. Because in onResume I call displayRecords again.

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes displayRecords is executing the Async, where you should use the above. If "adapter" is always null, make sure you're not setting it to null manually.

Comment: It's working now but it's not updating the adapter. I need to display new records but retain scroll position if I go back to list activity

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes make sure you add the new data to your adapter's data source before calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, for example: dataList.add(OBJECT) or dataList.addAll(LIST) and then notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in one of my old projects, added this code in  `onSaveInstanceState` and it worked:

```
// save index and top position
int index = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View view = listView.getChildAt(0);
int top = (view == null) ? 0 : view.getTop();
```

Then save it in `SharedPreferences` so you can go back to the same position:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putString(key1, index);
        edit.putString(key2, top);
        edit.commit();
```

You can set the previous state of the `ListView` by retrieving data from `SharedPreferences`, for example:

```
SharedPreferences sp =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());     
String _index = sp.getString("INDEX1", saved_index);
String _top = sp.getString("TOP1", saved_top);
```

Then use this after `setAdapter`:

```
listView.setSelectionFromTop(Integer.parseInt(_index), Integer.parseInt(_top));
```

**Note:** `onSaveInstanceState()` is a method used to store data before pausing the activity.

Comment: Even when you're calling the async in onResume()?

Comment: And how do you call to set the previous state of listview?

Comment: I think you need to save it before onResume() is called so you can go back to previous position.. I'll check how I did mine and get back to you.

Comment: Edited my answer and added how to set the previous state of `ListView`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, above is how I did mine.. so in your case, save the `ListView` position before calling async and then restore and set values after it's finished executing and after `setAdapter` by using `setSelectionFromTop`.. hopefully that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add property in `<ListView>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
android:transcriptMode
```

Values :

1. disabled - 0 : Scrolling is disabled
2. normal - 1 : If last item in list is visible to user then When new item is added at bottom through `notifyDataSetChanged()` call, the listview will scroll to show this item
3. alwaysScroll - 2 : The list will scroll to bottom no matter if last item is visible to user or not

Your case, `normal` is correct value and it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

save your clicked index and use it on later back

```
lv.setSelection(index);
```